# ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures.process

Tags: python, path

I have followed the procedure given in [How to use valgrind with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112989/how-to-use-valgrind-with-python) for checking memory leaks in my python code.

I have my python source under the path

```
/root/Test/ACD/atech
```

I have given above path in `PYTHONPATH`. Everything is working fine if I run the code with default python binary, located under `/usr/bin/`. 
I need to run the code with the python binary I have build manually which is located under

```
/home/abcd/workspace/python/bin/python
```

Then I am getting the following error

```
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures.process
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: PYTHONPATH should contain the directories that modules are in.  Did you add to PYTHONPATH or overwrite it?  Suggest you just add, unless you have more than one copy of the standard library modules.

Comment: Before I have set the PYTHONPATH it was empty. Just I have given my path using export.

Comment: I have tried by appending /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/futures to the PYTHONPATH. But now I am getting a different error:
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeLatin1

Comment: Try `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

Comment: Already tried that.. But no progress

Comment: Actually, the undefined symbol is probably not the PYTHONPATH, it looks like a library incompatibility.  Sorry to mislead you.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806831/ubuntu-11-04-lxml-import-etree-problem-for-custom-python

Answer (score 126, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.7 you must install this module :

```
pip install futures
```

Futures feature has never included in Python 2.x core. However, it's present in Python 3.x since Python 3.2.