# How to solve ImportError: cannot import name 'ProcessPoolExecutor'

Tags: python, python-3.x, polyglot

I'm getting this error when trying to using polyglot library for the first time.

```
from polyglot.text import Text, Word

word = Text("Preprocessing is an essential step.").words[0]
print(word.morphemes)
```

here is the full error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adeesha/PycharmProjects/theme_recomend/plyglot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from polyglot.text import Text, Word
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/polyglot-16.7.4-py3.5.egg/polyglot/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .base import Sequence, TokenSequence
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/polyglot-16.7.4-py3.5.egg/polyglot/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
ImportError: cannot import name 'ProcessPoolExecutor'
```

the version of Python 3.5.2

how I gonna solve this problem?

Comment: What are the contents of your folder? Maybe a file named `concurrent` exists?

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086530/importerror-no-module-named-concurrent-futures-process

Comment: no, I don't have folder name like that.