# undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf error while using 'lxml' on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, lxml

I am trying to import 'lxml' library into my python program as follows.

```
from lxml import etree
```

However, I am getting an error as 'undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf'. Here is the entire stack trace

```
File "xmlExtract.py", line 4, in <module>
from lxml import etree
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

I have carefully installed 'lxml' library including all of its dependencies (libxml2-dev, libxslt-dev, python-dev). I also have older version of python i.e 2.7 along with the new one python3.4. 
I tried setting variable PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
but still encountering the above error.

Could someone please help to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, and was able to get past it reinstalling lxml with:

```
pip install lxml --no-use-wheel
```

Depending on your version of pip, you may also use:

```
pip install lxml --no-binary :all:
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across this on one of my systems. On my system this comes from switching from system Python to a custom one but keeping the wheels around.

To fix this:

```
pip uninstall lxml
cd 
find .cache -name 'lxml*cp34*.whl' # check there is a wheel 
find .cache -name 'lxml*cp34*.whl' -delete # remove it
pip install lxml
```

Thanks to @moo-_- for solving this in another context. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6893563/2385133 for further details.

Comment: i chose this one cuz it was first. but they probably both work