# undefined symbol PyFPE_jbuf with spaCy

Tags: python, spacy

I am now getting the `undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf` when trying `import spacy` on an Ubuntu 17.10.

```
>>> import spacy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cli.info import info as cli_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .download import download
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .link import link
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/link.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..compat import symlink_to, path2str
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/compat.py", line 11, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import copy_array
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..train import Trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/train.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .optimizers import Adam, SGD, linear_decay
  File "optimizers.pyx", line 13, in init thinc.neural.optimizers
  File "ops.pyx", line 18, in init thinc.neural.ops
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cytoolz/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .functoolz import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

This is in Python 2.7, while Python 3.6 works ok. I have (at least) the problem with spaCy 2.0.5 and 2.0.6.

The `PyFPE_jbuf` error has been reported for a number of other projects, e.g., sklearn (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scikit-learn/+bug/1716004), numpy ([numpy undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190757/numpy-undefined-symbol-pyfpe-jbuf)), and lxml ([undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf error while using 'lxml' on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852646/undefined-symbol-pyfpe-jbuf-error-while-using-lxml-on-ubuntu)). Here the general suggestion seems to be a reinstall. My sklearn, numpy, and lxml imports work fine.

I have tried

```
pip install --upgrade spacy
```

and

```
pip uninstall spacy
pip install spacy
```

These commands do not help.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it myself. A forced reinstall including dependencies seems to work:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall spacy
```

SpaCy now imports:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spacy
>>>
```

An upgrade of `cytoolz` with `sudo pip install --upgrade cytoolz` did only fix the problem in `cytoolz`. A new exception appeared with `preshed`.